# Why doesn't Rust async block drop a value at the end of its scope?

Tags: rust

I ran into a curious issue while debugging some async code in Rust. Mainly, I have the following async block which is part of a test:

```rust
let s = Signal::new(0);

let s_clone = s.clone();

assert_eq!(s_clone.clone().await, 0);

assert_eq!(s.clone().await, 0);

join![s.for_each(|_| async {}), async {
  s_clone.set_and_wait(7).await;
  println!("s_clone should drop here...");
  drop(s_clone);
}];
```

The `join![]` code in this part doesn't matter too much, what matters is that the `Signal` I implemented is shared in such a way that only where there are no more unused signals do they stop and drop their values. Thus, if I omit the explicit `drop(s_clone);`, `s_clone` won't get dropped, causing `join![]` to never be able to complete.

#### The Question

In synchronous code, when a value reaches the end of the block, it just get's gropped, but why not in async? Why do I have to manually drop the value?

#### Additional Context

In case anyone is curious, I've implemented both `Future` and `Stream` for `Signal`. The future will only complete when all other pending signals cloned from the same source signal have finished reacting to any of their changes.

Comment: `drop(s_clone)` forces `s_clone` to be **moved** into the async block. (It's not specific to `drop()` - anything that consumed the value would have the same effect.) Omitting the `drop()` defaults to **borrowing** the value, which remains owned by the surrounding environment and so it won't be dropped by the async block. To force it to be dropped without an explicit `drop()`, use the `move` keyword, i.e. change `async` to `async move`.

Comment: wow...I have no idea how I missed that...thank you very much

Comment: This might be the answer, probably?

Answer (score 4):

`drop(s_clone)` makes the async block consume `s_clone` and thus forces `s_clone` to be **moved** into it. (This is not specific to `drop()` - doing anything that consumes the value would have the same effect.) Omitting the `drop()` reverts to the default closure behavior of **borrowing** the value. When the value is borrowed, it remains owned by the surrounding environment and so it won't (and can't) be dropped by the async block, which only holds a reference.

To force the async block to drop `s_clone` without an explicit `drop()`, use the `move` keyword, i.e. change `async` to `async move`. This will ensure that ownership of `s_clone` (and any other captured value) is moved into the async block, which will then drop it prior to exit.

> In synchronous code, when a value reaches the end of the block, it just get's gropped, but why not in async? Why do I have to manually drop the value?

The exact same thing can happen in synchronous code. Here is a non-async example equivalent to yours, where you can either uncomment the `move` or the `drop()` to have the value owned and dropped by the closure:

```
struct Dropper;

impl Drop for Dropper {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropper dropped");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dropper = Dropper;
    {
        let closure = /*move*/ || {
            let _ = &dropper;  // capture dropper
            //drop(dropper);
        };
        closure();
    }
    println!("closure dropped")
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=555191715bbb6e4405bf2575659595de)